# Jailkit - Missing file / directory colors?

Tags: 14.10

I have set up Jailkit on my server and wanted to create a new user that is restricted to this "jail".
That worked fine and so far through intense experimenting, I could not *escape* this jail :)

However, I noticed something:
Whenever I list files or directories via the *ls* command, it doesn't show them in different colors?
I'm used to seeing e.g. directories in the color *blue*, but every file is in gray.

Am I missing something, perhaps?

~ Greets.

Comment: Try `ls -l --color=always`

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, that actually works! But do I now have to do the "--color=always" EVERY TIME? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ls --color=always`

So you don't have to do it every time, add the line `alias ls="ls --color=always"` to the end of your `.bashrc`

Comment: I couldn't accept it since there was still a countdown on it, but this fixed it! :)
I probably just searched for the wrong things, mainly for "jailkit terminal colors" or the likes, since I didn't think it was related to "ls" in general